# C# - Differentiate between hard and soft page faults by using the WMI

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

I have built a C# program that monitors servers. The monitoring includes capturing details about the server, such as memory space, disk space etc..

This is done using the WMI.

I am also monitoring page faults for each server.

I would like to know if it is possible to differentiate between hard and soft page faults in C#?

Here is a cut of the code I am using:

```
        var machine = "machine";

        // get the scope of the remote server
        var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + machine + @"\root\cimv2");

        // the query as a string
        var queryString = "Select Name, ProcessId, PageFaults from win32_Process";

        // the query as an object
        var query = new ObjectQuery(queryString);

        // Run the query
        var worker = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        var results = worker.Get();

        pageFaults.WriteLine(machine);

        // Enumerate around each item in the results query
        foreach (ManagementObject item in results)
        {
            totalPages = totalPages + (int)(UInt32)item["PageFaults"];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total pages = {0}", totalPages);
        pageFaults.WriteLine("*{0}*",totalPages);
```

Comment: Could you clarify your meaning of soft page faults? Its a term that tends to have multiple meanings depending on who you ask. I would assume you mean something akin to TLB misses?

Comment: You can't get hard faults for a specific process.  Next best are [the Memory performance counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg590213%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Page Faults are soft+hard, Page Reads are hard.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Hard page fault: " Hard page faults occur when the page is not located in physical memory or a memory-mapped file created by the process." Soft page fault " a soft page fault occurs when the page is resident elsewhere in memory." I will continue with the code that I have, because I want page faults for the entire server. My source for hard/soft definitions is : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/06/10/the-basics-of-page-faults/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying **individual** process pagefaults/sec, you can use below mentioned query. As Hans has pointed out earlier, this pagefault is hard+soft both. But these tables get updated quite frequently, and if I am not wrong, **perfmon** also shows same data.

```
select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where NOT name = '_Total'
```

For cumulative

```
select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where name = '_Total'
```